# SQL - How to use a Case When to create a new column in a summary chart

Tags: sql, t-sql

I found a really nice query online to create a summary chart:

```
select 
    year([invoice posted date]) as SalesYear,
    month ([invoice posted date]) as SalesMonth,
    round(sum([INV Line Final Price]), 0) as TotalSales
from 
    [Invoice_Data22618]
group by 
    year([invoice posted date]), month ([invoice posted date])
order by 
    year([invoice posted date]), month ([invoice posted date])
```

This returns a result something like:

```
SalesYear | SalesMonth | TotalSales
2017      |  11           xxxxx
2017      |  12           xxxxx           
2018         1            xxxxx
2018         2            xxxxx
```

I'd now like to add a new column that is NewCustomerSales along the lines of:

```
case 
   when [customer date created] between '2017-11-01' and 2017-11-30' 
      then round(sum([INV Line Final Price]), 0) as NewCustSales, 
      else 0
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the `NewCustSales` to search the `SalesYear` and `SalesMonth` so I can see each month what percentage of my sales for the month are coming from new vs. existing customers. Both invoice posted date and customer date created are in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would help here

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be a little more complicated, because you need to filter non-new customers out of your pool. Something like this should work:

```
select year([invoice posted date]) as SalesYear,
month ([invoice posted date]) as SalesMonth,
round(sum([INV Line Final Price]),0) as TotalSales,
(SELECT round(sum([INV Line Final Price]),0)
 FROM [Invoice_Data22618] sub
 WHERE year(sub.[invoice posted date]) = year(main.[invoice posted date])
 AND month(sub.[invoice posted date]) = month(main.[invoice posted date])
 AND year(sub.[customer create date]) = year(main.[invoice posted date])
 AND month(sub.[customer create date]) = month(main.[invoice posted date])) AS NewCustSales
from [Invoice_Data22618] main
group by year([invoice posted date]), month ([invoice posted date])
order by year([invoice posted date]), month ([invoice posted date])
```

Comment: Well that seems to have worked pretty perfectly!!!  Thanks a lot. Just so I'm sure I understand what you did.  is the sub.column and main.column a special SQL command or does that just create duplicate columns that you can use for the comparisons?

Comment: Those are table aliases.

Comment: Are you sure you need the subquery? Can't you just count customers with create date in the same month?

Comment: You can use whatever you want there. For instance, you could use A and B or inside and outside. It’s just a way to identify the table. In this case, we want to make sure the results in the sub query match the month and year for the same row in the main query, hence the naming I used.